# How to upload and save file on physical location using angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I have input control for file and button in my HTML

HTML -

```
<input type="file" nv-file-select="" uploader="uploader"/>
<input type="button" value="Submit"/>
```

I want to upload file using this file upload control.
After adding file and hitting submit button, File should save on document folder located on my projects root directory.

I am using Visual studio tool to build this functionality.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24401680/file-uploading-in-a-local-drive-with-angularjs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File uploading in a local drive with angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24401680/file-uploading-in-a-local-drive-with-angularjs)

Comment: Don't you need a server for this kind of operation. What is the action you are performing on submit?

Comment: what you are using in back-end because your back-end code will do the actual task.

Comment: In backend m using ASP.NET MVC